# Android IllegalStateException: attempt to use Inflater after calling end

Tags: java, android, download, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Here is my Stacktrace:

```
<StackTrace>java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to use Inflater after calling end
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.checkOpen(Inflater.java:332)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.setInput(Inflater.java:312)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:106)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:374)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
    at com.myProgram.services.DownloadService.onHandleIntent(DownloadService.java:58)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
</StackTrace>
```

and here is the code from DownloadService:

```
 InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
 byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            receiver.send(U_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

58 line is:

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
```

This error occurs in random cases. Download service is used to download new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot close the downloading InputStream from a different thread than your download service (i.e. the one which is calling InputStream.read).

Do you have another thread that by any chance is trying to close the stream using InputStream.close() api? such a behavior will cause this kind of runtime exception. On more recent versions of OkHttp, a somewhat similar exception will be produced from the closing thread. See below for a reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1842